# TypeScript Generics error: left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I don't understand why I'm receiving the following error. I've declared the type of `first` as being a `number`. Please provide the correct code to make this work.

```
function divide<T, U>(first: T, second: U): number {
  return first / second;
}

const result = divide<number, number>(40, 2);
```

And here is the error which TypeScript outputs:

```
5:12 The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
    3 | const TitleBar = () => {
    4 |   function divide<T, U>(first: T, second: U): number {
  > 5 |     return first / second;
      |            ^
    6 |   }
    7 |
    8 |   const result = divide<number, number>(40, 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T and U are generic placeholders. The TypeScript compiler doesn't know that the `first` and `second` parameters will be of a compatible type for the divide operation. The return type of the function `!==` the parameter types.

This code compiles because now TypeScript knows that T and U are types that extend number.

```
function divide<T extends number, U extends number>(first: T, second: U): number {
  return first / second;
}

const result = divide<number, number>(40, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering that. But then what is the point of Generics if you're going to set their type anyway??? Why not just use a normal function definition. I thought the whole point of Generics is that the type could be set later on in the code.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't really have true support for generics. Look at a language like C++ that allows operator overloading and this type of function makes sense. Since there's no operator overloading in TypeScript, the compiler mandates that the parameter types to your function are compatible with the division operator.

Comment: You make great points technically, but if you think about it rationally, there is really no need for a TypeScript generic, because as soon as you want to do absolutely any operation on an argument, you have to define it EXACLTY like a normal function. E.g. `const getName = (name: string): string => name`. Basically, Generics in TypeScript looks to me like an asinine feature that only succeeds in obfuscating code.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they're useless in TypeScript. One use case that comes to mind is a generic interface with multiple typed implementations.

Comment: Agreed re a Generic interface  - but Generics for declaring functions types are utterly redundant, unless I'm missing something, because you have to explicitly declare the types of the arguments if your function does anything with them.